# Bash script TUI for database insert statement not working. Set bash builtin error message

Tags: bash, zenity

I have the following bash script that provides a Zentiy TUI to insert data into a database.

```
#!/bin/bash

    tip_run1="$(zenity --entry --text "ENTER number of tip runs:" --entry-text "1")"
     a=1

until
        [[ $tip_run1 -lt $a ]]
do
        input="$(zenity --forms --title="table tip_run" --text="Add a new tip run" --separator="," \
        --add-entry="ENTER start_time, e.g. 8:20: " \
        --add-entry="ENTER finish_time, e.g. 12:30: " \
        --add-entry="ENTER weight in kg, -t numeric: "\
    --add-entry="ENTER a note, -t text: ")"

psql -tA -U chh1 -d crewdb -c "SELECT SETVAL('tip_run_tip_runid_seq', (SELECT MAX(tip_runid) FROM tip_run), true);" >/dev/null 2>&1

startt="$(echo "$input" | awk -F, -v  OFS=, '{print $1}')"
finisht="$(echo "$input" | awk -F, -v  OFS=, '{print $2}')"

st="$( date --date="$startt" +%s  2>/dev/null )"
ft="$( date --date="$finisht" +%s 2>/dev/null )" 

if [ -n "$st" -a "$ft" ] ; then
    
    startt="$(date +%H:%M  -d "$startt"  )"
    finisht="$(date +%H:%M -d "$finisht" )"
    tzdiff="$(( ft - st ))"
else
    tzdiff=0
fi    

while [[  ( ( ! "$startt"   =~ ^[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$ ) && ( ! "$startt"  =~ ^[0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]$ ) ) || 
          ( ( ! "$finisht"  =~ ^[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$ ) && ( ! "$finisht" =~ ^[0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]$ ) ) || 
          ( "$tzdiff" -le 0 )  ]];
do
    var2="$(zenity --forms --title="start_time and/or finish_time are incorrect" --text "Add a start_time and a finish_time"  --separator="," \
                   --add-entry="WARNING! Something went wrong. Please enter a valid start_time, e.g. 8:20: " \
                   --add-entry="WARNING! Something went wrong. Please enter a valid finish_time, e.g. 12:30: ")"
    tzdiff=0
    
    if [ -n "$var2" ] ; then
       b1=$(echo "$var2" | cut -d, -f1 )
       b2=$(echo "$var2" | cut -d, -f2 )
       
       if [ -n "$b1" -a -n "$b2"  ] ; then
           tz1=$( date --date="$b1" +%s 2>/dev/null )
           tz2=$( date --date="$b2" +%s 2>/dev/null )
           
       if [ -n "$tz1" -a -n "$tz2" ] ; then
              startt=$(date +%H:%M -d "$b1" )
              finisht=$(date +%H:%M -d "$b2" )
              tzdiff=$(( tz2 - tz1 ))
           fi
       fi
    fi
done

var2="$startt,$finisht"

input="$( echo "$input" | awk -v vart="$var2" 'BEGIN {  FS="," } { print vart "," $3 "," $4 ; }' )"

input="$((IFS=, read -r  b c d e ; echo "${b}ttt,${c}ttt,${d}xxx,${e}www" )<<<"$input")"

IFS=,; set -f; set --$input; out=
for i in "$@"; do

        case "$i" in
                xxx) var2="$(zenity --forms --title="weight field in table tip_run" --text "Add a weight in kg"  --separator="," \
                                --add-entry="WARNING! You forgot to enter a weight. Please enter a valid weight, e.g. 12.5: ")"

                                until [[ ${var2} =~ ^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]] || [[ ${var2} = NULL ]]; do

                                        var2="$(zenity --forms --title="weight field in table tip_run" --text "Add a weight in kg"  --separator="," \
                                        --add-entry="WARNING! You either forgot to enter a weight or didn't enter a number. Please enter a valid weight, e.g. 12.5: ")"

                                done

                                out="$out,${var2}"                          
                                ;;
                
        NULLxxx) out="$out,${i/%xxx/}";;        
                *xxx) if [[ "${i/%xxx}" =~ ^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]]; then
            
            out="$out,${i/%xxx/}"
            
            else
                 until [[ ${var2} =~ ^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]] || [[ ${var2} = NULL ]]; do

                                        var2="$(zenity --forms --title="weight field in table tip_run" --text "Add a weight in kg"  --separator="," \
                                        --add-entry="WARNING! You either forgot to enter a weight or didn't enter a number. Please enter a valid weight, e.g. 12.5: ")"

                                done

                                out="$out,${var2}"
            fi
                                ;;
        *ttt) out="$out,'${i/%ttt/}:00'";;
                #TRUEbool) out="$out,${i/%bool/}";;
                #FALSEbool) out="$out,${i/%bool/}";;
                #*bool) echo "empty input not allowed"; exit 0;;
        NULLwww) out="$out,${i/%www/}";;
        www)            var2="$(zenity --forms --title="note field in table tip_run" --text "Add a note"  --separator="," \
                                --add-entry="WARNING! You either forgot to enter a note. Please enter a note or NULL: ")"

                                until [[ ! ${var2} = ""  ]]; do

                                        var2="$(zenity --forms --title="note field in table tip_run" --text "Add a note"  --separator="," \
                                        --add-entry="WARNING! You either forgot to enter a note or to enter NULL. Please enter a note or NULL: ")"

                                done
                
                if [[ ${var2} = "NULL"  ]]; then
                    out="$out,${var2}"
                else

                out="$out,\$\$${var2}\$\$"
                fi;;

        *www) out="$out,\$\$${i/%www/}\$\$";;
esac;
done

#echo "${out:1}"

echo "" >> /tmp/crew.txt
echo "" >> /tmp/crew.txt
echo "-- INSERT INTO tip_run:"  >> /tmp/crew.txt
echo "INSERT INTO tip_run (date_linkid, start_time, finish_time, weight, note) VALUES (${out:1});" >> /tmp/crew.txt

let a++

done
```

I know the individual components of the script work but when I run it I get the following error message:

```
./tip_run.txt: line 64: set: --: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
```

Line 64 is at the following location:

```
 62 input="$((IFS=, read -r  b c d e ; echo "${b}ttt,${c}ttt,${d}xxx,${e}www" )<    <<"$input")"
 63 
 64 IFS=,; set -f; set --$input; out=
 65 for i in "$@"; do
 66 
 67         case "$i" in
```

I have tried different options with set but none seem to work. Can anyone put me on the right track with this?

Comment: Note I have advised you before to run your scripts through [ShellCheck – shell script analysis tool](https://www.shellcheck.net/). Please see my answer.

Comment: `set --$input` – Did you mean `set -- $input`? Questions where there is a problem with code should follow the concept of [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659). The code in the current question is certainly not minimal.

Comment: Well, `set -- "$input"` and then `for i in "$@"` makes no sense. You had `set -- $INPUT` [here](https://superuser.com/q/1561084/432690) and the variable was unquoted for a reason. And there was a space after `--` for a reason. If you don't know how it works then maybe you should ask specifically about it (with mcve). Adding spaces or quotes without insight (like in [this comment](https://superuser.com/q/1566596/432690#comment2386163_1566603)) is [voodoo programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voodoo_programming). I may be able to help you reduce voodoo – but not by debugging large scripts.

Comment: yes I don't understand that hence the question in the first place. If I knew the answer as to where the problem lies my questions would undoubtedly be more polished. The reason I put the whole script in is because i thought it is important to derive an answer. I have tried to find stuff online on set but couldn't find anything specific to my problem. I had specifically asked about line 64 not to debug a whole script.

Comment: What I have ended up going with, which now works is:`IFS=,; set -f; set -- $input; out=
for i in "$@"; do
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `set --$input`, it "should" be `set -- $input`. Or maybe it shouldn't be here at all.

---

#### The purpose of `set -- $something` and how it works

Few answers to [one of your previous questions](https://superuser.com/q/1560809/432690) advised to use `set -- $OUTPUT`. The full relevant snippet was like:

```
IFS=,; set -f; set -- $OUTPUT
for i do …
```

<sup>Note: `for i do`, `for i; do` and `for i in "$@"; do` are equivalent.</sup>

In that question you wanted to split the content of the variable using `,` as delimiter. Then you wanted to loop over the resulting chunks. You tried to use `awk`. It was noted the shell can do this and the snippet is the way. Let's analyze how it works exactly.

The main idea is to use the fact an unquoted variable undergoes word splitting upon expansion. Normally an unquoted variable triggers filename generation as well (e.g. expansion of wildcards like `*` if they are stored in the variable). Usually you want neither filename generation nor word splitting, therefore the general rule is to [always double-quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) unless you know what you're doing. Among few cases where not quoting is justified there is `set -- $something`, but you need to know what you are doing. This is what you are doing:

- you specify `IFS=,` so future word splitting treats `,` as delimiter;
- by `set -f` you disable the filename generation mechanism.

After this an unquoted `$something` expands safely to zero or more words. Still you need to loop over them. It's easy to loop over positional parameters (i.e. parameters you can get with `$1`, `$2`, …; or with `$@` or (not equivalently) `$*` to get all of them at once; quoting is important).

[`set`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) is a shell builtin that can set or unset shell options (e.g. `set -f` we already know) and positional parameters. Arguments that don't look like options modify the array of positional parameters. E.g. `set foo bar` makes `$1` expand to `foo` and `$2` expand to `bar`.

Words from the expansion of `$something` can be assigned to positional parameters with `set $something` but this is flawed in at least two aspects:

1. If a word looks like an option to `set`, it will be treated as an option. The option may or may not be recognized as a valid (supported) option.
2. If `$something` expands to exactly zero words then `set $something` will end up as sole `set` which does not modify the array of positional parameters.

The first problem is general, not specific to `set`. Many tools (including `set`) support [double dash (`--`)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/108618) to solve it. The second problem is specific to `set`. The design of the tool makes `--` solve the second problem as well. I mean if `$something` expands to exactly zero words then `set -- $something` will end up as `set --` which does modify the array of positional parameters as expected: all positional parameters will be unset.

So `set -- $something` is a robust way to assign zero or more words from the expansion of `$something` to positional parameters you can then easily loop over.

Notes:

- It's possible to skip `set -- $something` and start a loop like this:

  ```
  IFS=,; set -f
  for i in $something; do
  ```

  But then you enter the loop with modified `IFS` and `set -f`. Using `set -- $something` and then `for i do` allows you to revert before `for`. In your current code you seem not to care about the modified `IFS` and `set -f`. In general they can backfire later ([you should already know](https://superuser.com/a/1564904/432690)).
- In Bash you can use a named array (e.g. `myarray` in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1560873/432690)) and loop over it.

---

#### What is wrong with `set --$something` or `set --"$something"`?

In case of `set --$something` (or `set --"$something"`) `--` is concatenated with the first word from the expansion of `$something` (or with the only word from the expansion of `"$something"`). There are some edge cases that would make `--` stay `--` but most likely it becomes `--whatever`. This string starts with `-`, so it looks like an option or options.

There are few conventions regarding options. Most tools support single-dash-single-character options (short options, e.g. `-a` or `-1`). Many tools support double-dash-multi-character options (long options, e.g. `--almost-all`). Few tools treat single-dash-multi-character options as single options (e.g. in `7z` there is `-bd` or `-bt`) but many will treat `-abc` like `-a -b -c`, if neither `-a` nor `-b` requires an option-argument. In general a tool can parse and interpret its arguments in any way it wants, so this can be complicated.

`set --whatever` does not treat `whatever` as a long option, it doesn't support long options at all. It looks `set --whatever` is almost like `set -- -w -h -a -t -e -v -e -r`, except this `--` does *not* work like the double dash elaborated earlier. Here `--` tries to work as a short option, a single-dash-single-character option where the single-character part happens to be a dash. But there is no such short option:

> ```
> set: --: invalid option
> ```

`--` needs to be a separate argument. By omitting the space after `--` you made `set` wrongly interpret its first argument as options. Quite amusing, regarding the fact that the main point of *properly used* `--` is to indicate the end of options.

---

#### What is wrong with `set -- "$something"`?

In a (now deleted) comment the idea of `set -- "$something"` appeared, probably because of the "always quote" rule. This expands `$something` to a single word. The main goal in the first place was to split to possibly multiple words, so quoting is certainly not the right thing to do.

Let's suppose for a while you really wanted `$something` as a single word, you did `set -- "$something"` and it worked well. In such case the consecutive `for i in "$@"; do` makes no sense because you're iterating over a *single* element. There's no need for a loop.

---

#### Do you really need `set`, `for` and `case`?

In your [already mentioned question](https://superuser.com/q/1560809/432690) you tested each field with the same code. Iterating over fields was a good idea.

In the current question:

- At some point you're passing the value of `$input` through `awk` and I strongly suspect that by design there are *exactly* four comma-separated fields afterwards.
- Then you're using `IFS=, read -r` to split `$input` to `$b`, `$c`, `$d` and `$e`; these are the fields.
- Then you're saving `${b}ttt,${c}ttt,${d}xxx,${e}www` altogether again.
- Then you're splitting it *again*, this time with `set -- $input`, so instead of `$b`, `$c`, `$d` and `$e` you have `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and `$4`.
- Then you're looping over the fields and you're using `case` to run different code for different fields. I mean `NULLxxx` can only match the third field (`${d}xxx`). You're using `xxx` to recognize the third field, but *you had it separated as `$d` earlier*. Why not testing `$d` for being `NULL` in the first place?

Splitting to positional parameters is useful if you don't know in advance how many fields you have. If you know you have exactly four, then

```
IFS=, read -r  b c d e
```

in the main shell will give you four well-defined separate variables to work with. You can still loop with `for i in "$b" "$c" "$d" "$e"; do`, but since in your original code only `${b}ttt` and `${c}ttt` share a case they can match (`*ttt`), it makes sense to loop over `"$b"` and `"$c"`, then parse `"$d"` and `"$e"` separately. The code common for `"$b"` and `"$c"` is so simple you can as well repeat it without introducing a loop:

```
out="$out,'$b:00'"
out="$out,'$c:00'"
```

and then:

```
# what to do if $d is empty
# what to do if $d is NULL
# what to do if $e is NULL
# what to do if $e is empty
# what to do if $e is valid
# etc.
```

The approach where you mark different fields with `ttt` or `xxx` makes some sense if you want to be able to quickly upgrade the code to support additional fields that need to be validated like the already supported fields. Is this the case? Even then splitting and concatenating and splitting again seems overcomplicated.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, that is very useful!

Answer (score 0):

#### Can anyone put me on the right track with this?

As always, with bash scripts that don't quite work, I run them through [ShellCheck – shell script analysis tool](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Your script generates the following errors/warnings:

```
$ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 23:
if [ -n "$st" -a "$ft" ] ; then
              ^-- SC2166: Prefer [ p ] && [ q ] as [ p -a q ] is not well defined.
 
Line 45:
       if [ -n "$b1" -a -n "$b2"  ] ; then
                     ^-- SC2166: Prefer [ p ] && [ q ] as [ p -a q ] is not well defined.
 
Line 49:
       if [ -n "$tz1" -a -n "$tz2" ] ; then
                      ^-- SC2166: Prefer [ p ] && [ q ] as [ p -a q ] is not well defined.
 
Line 62:
input="$((IFS=, read -r  b c d e ; echo "${b}ttt,${c}ttt,${d}xxx,${e}www" )<<<"$input")"
       ^-- SC1102: Shells disambiguate $(( differently or not at all. For $(command substition), add space after $( . For $((arithmetics)), fix parsing errors.
 
Line 64:
IFS=,; set -f; set --$input; out=
                     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
IFS=,; set -f; set --"$input"; out=
 
Line 125:
echo "" >> /tmp/crew.txt
^-- SC2129: Consider using { cmd1; cmd2; } >> file instead of individual redirects.
 
Line 130:
let a++
^-- SC2219: Instead of 'let expr', prefer (( expr )) .

$
```

I suggest you take a close look at the messages output for lines 62 and 64.

Note that if you run the script yourself through ShellCheck you will see that the output includes clickable links to more information about the  various messages produced.

Comment: Thanks David. I did that however. I tried adding a space at line 62 such as `"$(  (`, I read through the comments and I double quoted at line 64 `--"$input"`. It still does not work.

Comment: As usual the bash expert Kamil has arrived. He may have hit the nail on the head...